# Problem in bibliography with applemac

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, mac, underline

I have one problem with the bibliography: I need to work on TexMaker with the package inputenc applemac because my supervisor absolutely wants that I use that, but when the bibliography appears, the name of the magazins and of the books are underlined, but I don't want that. 
How can I erase the underline ?

This is my preamble, which my supervisor has provided. Do you see anything in there which might account for this:

```
\documentclass[11pt, leqno, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}% Codage du fichier
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{euscript}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=5.5cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Could you post a MWE? It's not likely that `inputenc` would change the formatting of the bibliography in this way. The most important question is what bibliographystyle you are using, and whether you are changing anything in your preamble.

Comment: I think it is the `ulem` package which is doing this.

Comment: You're right! I have deleted this package ulem, and the underline has disappeared in the bibliography! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect you see is probably the result of loading `ulem` which by default changes `\emph` to use underlining. Try loading that package with the option `normalem`

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
```

Or remove it altogether if you don't need underlining.